# Recent books on JVM?

Tags: java, jvm

I'm after a book to learn about the internals of the [Java virtual machine.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine)

I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1426750/best-books-on-jvm) but it is two years old now.

Are there any newer JVM books which reflect the recent updates?

Would any of the books from that link be good to read or should I avoid any of them because they are too out of date?

Do you know any books which have been published since?

Comment: This question is still not constructive.

Comment: *<Java Performance - The definitive guide>* 2014, this new book is great for jvm & java turing.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

One of the best Java books I have read.

http://www.pearsonhighered.com/educator/product/Java-Performance/9780137142521.page

Its called "Java Performance" but its really about low level, useful things to know about the JVM from one of the developers. i.e. not just about performance. Published 2012.

About the authors

http://java.sun.com/javaone/2009/javauniversity_bios.jsp#chunt

http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1757633

BTW: Most books take 1 - 2 years to write/publish so if you want the most up to date information, it best to find the information yourself (after reading a good book so you know all the basics).

Comment: I just start to read it, seems to be an great book for both jvm & performance.

Answer (score 13):

Personally I learned everything about JVM internals from the [Java Virtual Machine Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/) by Tim Lindholm and Frank Yellin. I have a few other books which pick apart the same content, but that's still the best. Once you understand the fundamentals of the JVM then its easy to apply the more recent updates without any trouble.

It would be better if there was a specific section of the JVM that you wanted to understand better, then recommendations could be more focused.

Comment: Agree, the specification is the most *unambiguous* guide.