# How java program interacts with Compiler?

Tags: java, computer-science

I'm trying to understand, how java program interacts with compiler.

Lets assume, we write simple java language on plane text file. At the core level its stored in bits pattern on disk.

Java's compiler is separate identity, which is some sort of bits pattern only.

This pattern can consume something which it understands. Consumes java bit pattern so called java program and produce instructions to be processed by processor.

Where this process happens, in memory or processor ? Process where java compiler eats java and produce instructions to understand by processor.

My understanding says, memory is just for loading which we are able to see on screen, coming from disk or processor. Java program and compiler code both exists on screen and should be loaded in memory to go further.

Then how and in what sequence creation of processor's instructions created ? Where they are interacting and how?

Can anyone please help me understand this? Very curious to know. Any book or reference will also work.

Comment: You probably looking to learn more about JVM (Java Virtual Machine). You can obviously google for learning resources, but [this](https://www.javaworld.com/article/3272244/what-is-the-jvm-introducing-the-java-virtual-machine.html) article seems to be a good starting point. You might also want to take a look at [Inside the Java Virtual Machine](https://www.artima.com/insidejvm/blurb.html) book by Bill Venners (it's really old book, like 20 years old, but it's the only JVM book that I can personally recommend). [alse see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9453444/recent-books-on-jvm).

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty much the same as any compiler system.  The compiler reads source text from a file (.java, in this case), and writes equivalent instructions to another file (.class, in this case).

The execution of the compiler proceeds like the execution of any computer program: the processor executes instructions that come from memory, and those instructions read and write memory.  It does not seem appropriate to call this "in memory" or "in the processor" - it's "in the computer" as a whole.

---

More detail:

The compiler is, when running, instructions loaded in memory being executed by the processor. The compiler will execute instructions to read the .java files from disk into memory so that it, the compiler, can translate the Java code.  The compiler will execute instructions to write the compiled code out to disk (as .class files).

The compiler and Java program are not running at the same time. The compiler translates the Java program entirely before that program (the 'application program') is run.  First compile .java to .class files; then execute the .class files.

The application program is, when running, instructions loaded in memory being executed by the processor. (This is a simplification for this explanation, avoiding the existence of a thing called the JVM. It does not materially change the overall idea).

This isn't so much about Java as it is about how computers work in general. Data have to be accessible to the processor, and that means that the data need to be in memory. The processor's instructions, i.e., an executing program, can't manipulate data any other way (to an approximation; there are exceptions that are not applicable at the level of explanation we're going for here)

Comment: If compiler is able to read something, then he cant do in memory, right ? It has to go through from processor. So point is how java program and compiler both interacts processor at the same time ?and

Comment: It's unclear to me how you think anything "interacts" with the processor. Any program that is running **is** simply the processor executing instructions, so there's not two entities there than can "interact",  Consider the compiler as simply a sequence of instructions in memory.

Comment: Now makes sense, but tell me one thing, if there are so many java files, so read instruction of compiler will read all java files to get specific file in which main method is written ..?

Comment: Yes, a Java program is often several .java files. The compiler is told about all files for a program - either explicitly or (more usually I think) "all .java files in this folder".  It not so much actively looks for **main** but simply checks after processing whether **main** was found.